# Unable to import class that was exported two times (Typescript)

Tags: typescript

I'm unable to import a class that was exported two times.

**a.ts**

```
import * as moduleB from "./b";
export class A {
  b: moduleB.B;
  constructor() {
    this.b = new moduleB.B();
    this.b.hello();
  }
}
```

**b.ts**

```
import {C} from "./c";
export const B = C;
```

**c.ts**

```
export class C {
  hello() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
}
```

The error message is:

```
a.ts(3,14): error TS2305: Module '"b"' has no exported member 'B'.
```

The problem seems to be that the type of C has not been probably exported with "export const B = C;". The error would go away if I change "b: moduleB.B;" to just "b: any;".
How can I fix this?

Using a default export in b.ts would work but I want to export several things in b.ts so that's not an option. I'm using Typescript 1.7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're declaring property `b : moduleB.B` in `a.ts` you're defining `b` to be of the *type* `moduleB.B`, but you've defined `moduleB.B` as a *const*. Since the const is a reference to the constructor function of `C` the `new moduleB.B()` does compile.

You could write `export type B = C` in `b.ts` instead, but that would then *only* export the type alias which would mean `b : moduleB.B` would compile, but `new moduleB.B()` wouldn't since you did not export constructor function.

Use `export {C as B}` (full alias) in `b.ts` to achieve exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Great. This solved my problem. I was unaware of this export syntax.